# Animate between fontawesome icons not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I've created an animation to cycle through a set of individual FontAwesome icons.  It is working on latest Firefox and Chrome, but on IE (10, 11, Edge) the icon simply doesn't change.

To prove that IE is at least trying to animate, I've added the colour CSS.

Is this something that just can't be done on IE with CSS alone?

```css
i::before {
  animation: battery 5s infinite;
  font-size:2em;
}
@keyframes battery {
  0% { content: "\f244"; color:red; }
  25% { content: "\f243"; color:green; }
  50% { content: "\f242"; color:blue; }
  75% { content: "\f241"; color:yellow; }
  100% { content: "\f240"; color:purple; }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<i class="fas fa-battery-empty"></i>
```

Comment: you can stack the 5 icons and animate the opactiy of each one

Comment: Interesting approach, I will give it a go

Comment: Animating the content property is not supported in IE: https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/

Comment: Thanks @heatherhtml - at least that's added confirmation of why it's not happening  in IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented, you can try with stacking icons:

```css
i.fas {
  animation: battery 5s infinite;
  opacity:0;
  color:red;
}

i.fas:nth-child(2) {animation-delay:1s;}
i.fas:nth-child(3) {animation-delay:2s;}
i.fas:nth-child(4) {animation-delay:3s;}
i.fas:nth-child(5) {animation-delay:4s;}

@keyframes battery{
  0%,20% { /* 20 = 100 / 5 */
    opacity:1;
  }
  21%,100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
  <i class="fas fa-stack-1x fa-battery-empty"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-stack-1x fa-battery-quarter"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-stack-1x fa-battery-half"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-stack-1x fa-battery-three-quarters"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-stack-1x fa-battery-full"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your snippet doesn't appear to work with IE11?

Comment: @freefaller because of the CSS variable, replace them with `animation-delay:xs`

Comment: Excellent - thank you... that's definitely something I can work with. Will get back to you

Comment: Thanks again, also for showing me the `fa-stack-1x` which I wasn't aware of

Comment: @freefaller you can find more details in the doc: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons

Answer (score 1):

For IE, you may look instead at text-indent and move the icon steps by steps instead updating the content value.

```css
i::after {
  animation: battery 10s infinite;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  text-indent: -1.25em;
  content: " \f244  \f243 \f242 \f241 \f240";
  white-space: nowrap;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}

i {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 2em;
}

@keyframes battery {/* update values and steps to your needs */
  0% {
    text-indent: -1.25em;
    color: green;
  }
  19.9999% {
    text-indent: -1.25em;
  }
  20% {
    text-indent: -2.75em;
    color: green;
  }
  39.999% {
    text-indent: -2.75em;
  }
  40% {
    text-indent: -4em;
  }
  59.999% {
    text-indent: -4em;
    color: blue;
  }
  60% {
    text-indent: -5.25em;
  }
  79.999% {
    text-indent:-5.25em;
    color: orange;
  }
  80% , 100%{
    text-indent: -6.5em;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<i class="fas fa-battery-empty"></i>
```

Comment: Nice idea, but the opacity answer feels like a better solution. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the SVG sprites with the JS version of font-awesome then the CSS is slightly different.

The font-awesome JS removes the fas class and turns it into a data-prefix property so you'll have to add an identifier to the `<span>`

```
.battery svg {
    animation: battery 5s infinite;
    opacity: 0;
    color: red;
}

.battery svg:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

.battery svg:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

.battery svg:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

.battery svg:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes battery {
    0%, 20% { /* 20 = 100 / 5 */
        opacity: 1;
    }

    21%, 100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

...

```
<script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span class="fa-stack fa-4x battery">
    <i class="fas fa-stack-1x fa-battery-empty"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-stack-1x fa-battery-quarter"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-stack-1x fa-battery-half"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-stack-1x fa-battery-three-quarters"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-stack-1x fa-battery-full"></i>
</span>
```